# Flink Python Datastream API Kafka Consumer - NoClassDefFoundError ByteArrayDeserializer Error

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I have an error on Py4j side of the PyFlink. Code is below:

```
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
env.add_jars("file:/" + os.getcwd() + "/jar_files/" + "flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.15.0.jar")
type_info = Types.ROW_NAMED(['id', 't', 'l', 't', 'm', "a", "e"],
                                [Types.STRING(), Types.LIST(Types.STRING()), Types.STRING(), Types.FLOAT(),
                                 Types.STRING(), Types.FLOAT(),
                                 Types.STRING()])
json_row_schema = JsonRowDeserializationSchema.builder().type_info(type_info).build()
kafka_props = {'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'}
kafka_consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer("test", json_row_schema, kafka_props)
kafka_consumer.set_start_from_earliest()
## Stream
type_info = Types.ROW([Types.STRING(), Types.PICKLED_BYTE_ARRAY()])
serialization_schema = JsonRowSerializationSchema.Builder() \
        .with_type_info(type_info) \
        .build()
kafka_producer = FlinkKafkaProducer(
        topic='testmodels',
        serialization_schema=serialization_schema,
        producer_config={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'}
    )
```

The error is:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArrayDeserializer
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer.setDeserializer(FlinkKafkaConsumer.java:323)
..more..
```

I also have a dummy map function, which is not relevant here because the error is coming from

```
def _get_kafka_consumer(topics, properties, deserialization_schema, j_consumer_clz):
    if not isinstance(topics, list):
        topics = [topics]
    gateway = get_gateway()
    j_properties = gateway.jvm.java.util.Properties()
    for key, value in properties.items():
        j_properties.setProperty(key, value)

    j_flink_kafka_consumer = j_consumer_clz(topics,
                                            deserialization_schema._j_deserialization_schema,
                                            j_properties)
    return j_flink_kafka_consumer
```

The thing I tried are:

- Adding `env.add_jars("file:/" + os.getcwd() + "/jar_files/" + "kafka-clients-3.2.0.jar")` to code.
- Adding another java_import as `java_import(gateway.jvm, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.*")` in `import_flink_view' method.
- Use `flink-connector-kafka-1.15.0.jar` and `kafka-clients-3.2.0.jar` together.

They did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyflink uses .jar files under `~/miniconda3/envs/<env_name>/lib/<pythonversion>/site_packages/pyflink/lib/` while linking to jvm. Moving the `flink-connector-kafka-1.15.0.jar` and `kafka-clients-3.2.0.jar` under this folder may solve your issue.

Comment: Surprised it wouldnt use `~/.m2`

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same.